# Proof or counterproof for $\forall x (x = f(y)) \implies \forall y (y = f(x))$

Tags: functions, predicate-logic

I was wondering about the following fact:

$\forall x (x = f(y)) \implies \forall y (y = f(x))$

I think this is not true, but I can't find a counterexample but not I can prove it is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: for example f(x) = x ^ 2...?

Comment: What is $y$ in $\forall x(x=f(y))$?

Comment: If you see it from a preidcate-logic-viewpoint it is a free variable.

Comment: No, it is $\forall$ on both sides.. [Note: I'm female]

Comment: Inverses have nothing to do with it, it's just change of variables. Both antecedent and consequent say $\forall u\,(u = f(v))$, with a different free variable $v$ in both subformulas. It implicitly means $$\text{for all functions $f$, $\forall v\,\forall w\,(\forall x\,(x=f(v)) \to \forall y\,(y=f(w))$}$$. The antecedent $\forall x(x=f(v))$ is false for any function, so the entire inner formula is true.

Comment: Yes, this is a vacuous truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by the previous answer, we cannot find a counter-example because the formula is *valid*.

We can prove it with *Natural Deduction* [*Note* : in order to avoid mistakes, I'll use *parameters* : $a,b,\ldots$ as free variables.] :

1) $∀z \ (z=f(a))$ --- premise

2) $\exists z \ \lnot (z=f(b))$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\lnot (c=f(b))$ --- assumed [b] by $\exists$-elim, from 2)

4) $a=f(a)$ --- from 1) by $\forall$-elim

5) $b=f(a)$ --- from 1) by $\forall$-elim

6) $c=f(a)$ --- from 1) by $\forall$-elim

7) $a=b$ --- from 4) and 5) by the rules : $(=\text{symmetric})$ and $(=\text{transitive})$ [see : Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA123) (2007), page 123]

8) $f(a)=f(b)$ --- from 7) by the rule : $(= \text{term})$ [$s=t \vdash r[s/x] = r[t/x]$; see : Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA124) (2007), page 124]

9) $c=f(b)$ --- from 6) and 8) by $(=\text{transitive})$

10) $\bot$ --- from 3) and 9)

11) $\bot$ --- from 2), 3) and 10) by $\exists$-elim, discharging [b]

> 12) $\lnot \exists z \ \lnot (z=f(b))$ --- from 2) and 11) by $\lnot$-intro, discharging [a].

Thus, with the equivalence between $\forall$ and $\lnot \exists \lnot$ and $\to$-intro, we can conclude with :

> > $\vdash ∀z \ (z=f(a)) \to ∀z \ (z=f(b))$.

Comment: This looks very nice. However, I can't get the step 8).

Comment: It's nothing different from : "if $2=1+1$, then $2 \times 3 = (1+1) \times 3$ ...

Comment: Now I am interested in proofing: $s = t \vdash r(s) = r(t)$.

Comment: I'm looking exactly for this. It seems to be a little bit tricky

Comment: ...and I guess the conclusion of your proof should be: $\vdash \forall z (z = f(a)) \implies \forall z (z = f(b))$

Answer (score 0):

$\forall x(x=f(y))\to \forall y(y=f(x))$ is vacuously true.

Perhaps it will be clearer if we alpha replace the bound tokens for both quantifiers

$\forall z(z=f(y))\to \forall z(z=f(x))$

$\forall z(z=f(y))$ is a fallacy, (its false for any entity $y$ and and function $f$) so the implication is vacuously true.

Comment: Can I prove this using natural deduction for predicate logic?
Something like: $\forall x (x = f(y)) \vdash \forall y (y = f(x))$

Comment: Or is there any function f which makes the first part of the implication true?

Comment: Every $f(y)$ has a unique value; it can not equal every value. @今天春天

Comment: So f(y) can be 10. If I assume that my universe is $\mathbb{N}$, this does not hold for all x...

Comment: @Cloudscape what do you mean?

Comment: A trivial model would be a single-value universe of discourse. @今天春天

Comment: Can you give me a model where this assumption is actually true?

Comment: Trivially: $f:\{0\}\to\{0\}, \qquad \forall z\in\{0\} \; (z=f(0))\to\forall z\in\{0\}\; (z=f(0))$

Comment: ...and something which makes it false?

Comment: $(\forall z)[z= f(y)]$ is true exactly in the models with one element in their domain. It is not a fallacy, as the answer suggests. The overall equivalence in the question is valid, but it is not vacuous. It holds because both sides of the equivalence say that all elements of the domain are equal to each other.